# Best practices for storing content in secure area

Tags: node.js, microservices

In our project we have separate login page and several SPAs which user can access only after proper authentication.
All static content is placed in public CDN. But html files of SPAs are stored in DB and delivered to user by index service.
We don't want to store html files in DB because it is inconvenient for us.

What is the best way to store html files in secure area?

Comment: Store them in the file system and follow OWASP recomendations: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System

Comment: you can store the html file as EJS template in the file system itself with server side rendering and passing the sensitive information from the server side: https://ejs.co/

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure whats the purpose behind securely storing html files, instead you should serve the pages and validate the REST calls based on User's Authorization settings.